# Step references task 'InvokeRESTAPI' at version '1.152.3' which is not valid for the given job target

Tags: azure-devops, uipath

How to resolve the below error in Azure DevOps

Step references task 'InvokeRESTAPI' at version '1.152.3' which is not valid for the given job target

Comment: This has nothing to do with UiPath. Also add a screenshot. Not sure what you are doing.

Comment: We are using Ui Path orchestrator API in Azure DevOps as a agentless Job. Getting above error while running the job.

Comment: Do you have a link about the agentless job or how you integrated it?